# covariance of two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, covariance

I am trying to compute the covariance between two vectors in matlab:

```
x = [1:10]
y = [21:30]
cov(x,y)
```

This returns the matrix of covariance and variance. I just want 1 number: the covariance between the two vectors.  How does one get this in matlab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only have two one-dimensional vectors, the number you're looking for is the (1,2) element of the output of `cov`. By definition, the covariance matrix contains variances on its diagonal and covariance values on off-diagonal values.

Comment: ok, i guess the answer is then that i need to subset that thing every time. thanks! --alex

Comment: @Ansari do the same is valid when considering two matrices?

Comment: Can anyone confirm that subsetting every time is really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `x` in one realization of a random variable, so is `y`. Then `cov(x',y')` will give you the covariance matrix, where the diagonal entries are the variance of `x` and `y`, and the off diagonal element is the their covariance. Note `cov(x',y')` is symmetric matrix.